Isn't it possible to display text over a video?
I would like to have text being displayed on top of a video. I tried both multimedia and media9, as soon as the video starts, the text disappears. I also tried creating multiple tikzpicture environments, without success.
Here is the MWE
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia, tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[at=(current page.center)] {\movie[poster, open]{}{video.mov}};
\node[at=(current page.center)] {Isn't it possible to display this text over the video??};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


No, it is not possible. Video is displayed within so-called PDF Annotations which live in a separate layer on top of the page content. The same applies by the way to other annotation types such as links.

If the text is entirely within the borders of the video, you could use a video editing tool to embed the text in the video. If you don't need anything fancy, you could use ffmpeg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50749822/2777074

I'll have to do this then… however it was not just text but full tikz illustrations :/ But thanks.

@AlexG, can you make it an answer instead?

I am about writing one ;)

@Jav You could create an image from your tikz illustrations and add it to the video, e.g. https://video.stackexchange.com/a/32349

good ref, thanks.

It is possible with SVG. Unlike PDF, HTML5 standards and their implementation by modern web browsers indeed allow overlaying video content with graphics and text. The example below embeds a YouTube video, but local embeds are possible too (see media4svg documentation and examples).
Click to open:

Typeset with
latex example
latex example
dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 --bbox=papersize --zoom=-1 --page=- --linkmark=none example

\documentclass[dvisvgm]{beamer}

\usepackage{media4svg}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Graphics over video}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt]{\includemedia[width=\linewidth,height=0.5625\linewidth,youtube,controls]{}{5p_SuO96Jd4}};
  \pic[duck/water=blue,shift={(2,0)},scale=0.4] {duck};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


By design, video and other interactive elements are implemented in PDF as so-called PDF Annotations that live in a separate layer on top of the page content. Therefore, they are always displayed on top of text and graphics, no matter in which order they appear in the TeX input. As for hyperlinks, the link text is part of the page content, but the link rectangle is part of the PDF annotation.
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[urlbordercolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] {\Huge\url{https://ctan.org}};
\node [fill=green, inner sep=2cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Instead of using tikz overlays to add texts or images, you could use various video editing tools to directly add the text or image to your video.
https://video.stackexchange.com/a/32349 shows an example how to add an image on top of your video. So if you have some nice video of a "pond", you could add some ducks with
ffmpeg -i Stunning_Heddon_s_Mouth_-_North_Devon_Coast_Devon_UKDaysOut-Emma_Spears-UYkjBbnVt1c.mp4 -i DuckScout.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:255:enable='between(t,0,60)'" \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy \
output.mp4


